# unable to float menu icon on right and still have have icon on left

Tags: html, css

I've tried loads of combinations of floats, display: inline-blocks and position: relative or absolute.

Can't seem to get the menu bar and logo on either side of the same line on the mobile version of the site.

Here is the site: http://goo.gl/3VONrG

```
<div class="main-header bg-main-header" id="header_top">
    <div class="main-center">
        <!-- left content on header -->
        <div class="f-left f-left-all">
            <!-- fix logo middle -->
            <table class="fix-logo">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="<?php echo home_url()?>" class="logo"><img src="<?php echo $website_logo[0];?>" alt="<?php echo $general_opts->get_site_title();  ?>" /></a>   
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div id="hide-show-button" style="margin-top: 30px;"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div id="hide-show-button"></div>
            <div class="slogan"></div>
        </div>
```

Here is the CSS code:

```
#hide-show-button {
        float: right !important;
        background: url("images/menu-icon-dna.png") no-repeat right top/ auto 30px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        height: 50px !important;
        width: 70px !important;
        margin-bottom: 30px !important;
        margin-top: 30px !important;
        z-index: 999;
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What icon on the left are you talking about? I can see the logo and the menu icon only?

Comment: did that solve your problem?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:** use `display: flex;`

> For cross-browser support: use `display: inline-block;`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are after such a solution to put the show-hide button at the right:

```css
.fix-logo{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
#hide-show-button {
  border: 1px solid #121256;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #7878bc;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-header bg-main-header" id="header_top">
  <div class="main-center">
    <div class="f-left f-left-all">
      <div class="fix-logo">
        <a href="#" class="logo"><img src="http://www.alicejoeconsulting.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/alice_logo2.png" alt="" /></a>
        <div id="hide-show-button">Button</div>
      </div>
      <div class="slogan"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```